# Highcharts series data array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts

From an ajax call I get the following data back:

```
18,635,21,177,20,165,22,163,24,162,25,145,19,143,23,139,26,112,27,110,28,104,30,91,29,88,31,68,32,57,36,55,34,53,33,51,35,46,37,44,39,42,43,39,42,39,41,38,38,37,44,36,45,34,48,31,40,31,47,27,49,23,46,21,50,21,52,17,55,17,53,16,51,15,54,12,58,6,57,6,59,4,63,4,56,3,62,2,64,2,100,2,68,1,78,1,60,1,97,1,70,1,65,1,69,1,71,1
```

Of which every even number should be the key and every odd the value. But I have no idea how to parse it as highcharts data. Somehow I end up with the key being "slice" if I use JSON.parse and the only way I can get it to work normally is by placing it directly into the series data like this (after seperating the odd and even into seperate arrays):

```
[names[0] + ' years old', parseFloat(values[0])]
```

Which is great. But then I need to loop through the arrays somehow, pushing everything into the series data and I don't know how to do that. If I make a for loop with this data, how do I insert into the highcharts series data?

Comment: Is separating the data in two arrays is your problem? can you share some code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have that series data in an array, you can process it as follows:

```
var myData = [18, 635, 21, 177, 20, 165, 22, 163, 24, 162, 25, 145, 19, 143,
             23, 139, 26, 112, 27, 110, 28, 104, 30, 91, 29, 88, 31, 68, 32,
             57, 36, 55, 34, 53, 33, 51, 35, 46, 37, 44, 39, 42, 43, 39, 42, 
             39, 41, 38, 38, 37, 44, 36, 45, 34, 48, 31, 40, 31, 47, 27, 49,
             23, 46, 21, 50, 21, 52, 17, 55, 17, 53, 16, 51, 15, 54, 12, 58, 6,
             57, 6, 59, 4, 63, 4, 56, 3, 62, 2, 64, 2, 100, 2, 68, 1, 78, 1, 60,
             1, 97, 1, 70, 1, 65, 1, 69, 1, 71, 1];
var mySeries = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
        mySeries.push([myData[i], myData[i + 1]]);
        i++
    }
```

Once you have your series data in 'mySeries', you can just set your chart data using:

```
series:[{
    data: mySeries
}]
```

Alternatively, if you want to add the data after rendering the chart, you can add the series data dynamically using:

```
chart.series[0].setData(mySeries);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cm3Ps/ (press the 'Add My Data' button).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the function requires parameter as array of int.

Assume you get a function

```
drawChartFunction(data) {
    // some code here
    series: [{ data: data}]
}
```

You can try it:

```
array = {9,8,7,6}
var series = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    series.push([i, array.[i]]); 
}
```

After the `for` executed, your `series` likes

```
0,9
1,8
2,7
3,6
```

Then, you call `drawChartFunction(series)`

So your chart is drawn by using 4 points `0 1 2 3` with their values `9 8 7 6`